# Cast TypeScript ( ERROR TypeError )

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-http

O Problema é o seguinte, por meio de um serviço(`ModeloService`), recebo um array de `Modelo`, onde `Modelo` é uma classe, acontece que não estou conseguindo ter acesso aos métodos dessa classe, pois o `cast` no serviço não está sendo feito corretamente, ao invés do `cast` ser feito para um `array` de `Modelo`, fica só um array de um objeto javascript normal, porém, tipado com `Modelo`.

O `http` injetado é do `Angular2`.

Segue o código com as classes mencionadas:

Tenho a seguinte classe `TypeScript`, que representa um modelo(domain):

```
export class Modelo{
  id: number;
  type: string;
  size: number;

  constructor() {

  }

  public allowSize(): boolean {
    return this.type != null && (this.type.toLowerCase() == 'size');
  }

}
```

E o seguinte serviço:

```
@Injectable()
export class ModeloService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getAll(): Observable<Modelo[]> {
    return this.http.get(myEnvironment.MODELO_SERVICE_PATH)
      .map(res => <Modelo[]> res.json());
  }

}
```

Ao tentar usar esse método `allowSize()`, recebo o seguinte erro: `ERROR TypeError: modelo.allowSize is not a function`

```
modeloService.getAll()
  .subscribe(array=> array.forEach(modelo => console.log(modelo.allowSize())),
    error => console.log(error));
```

Ao printar `modelo` no console, não recebo um objeto `Modelo`, só recebo um objeto javascript normal com key and values:

```
{id: 1;   type: 'size';   size: '10'}
```

A maneira que achei para resolver o problema foi criando o objeto, da seguinte maneira:

```
getAll(): Observable<Modelo[]> {
  return this.http.get(myEnvironment.MODELO_SERVICE_PATH)
    .map(res => {

      return (<Modelo[]> res.json()).map(modelo => {
        let modeloToReturn = new Modelo();
        modeloToReturn.id = modelo.id;
        modeloToReturn.type= modelo.type;
        modeloToReturn.size = modelo.size;

        return modeloToReturn;
      })

    });
}
```

Resolve, mas causa outro problema que é eu ter que ficar evoluindo esse serviço sempre que eu evoluir meu modelo, não existe uma forma desse cast ser feito automaticamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decidi resolver o problema criando instânciando um objeto Modelo, aproveitar a orientação a objetos.

Da maneira como coloquei no post:

**modelo.service.ts**

```
getAll(): Observable<Modelo[]> {
  return this.http.get(myEnvironment.MODELO_SERVICE_PATH)
    .map(res => {

      return (<Modelo[]> res.json()).map(modelo => {
        let modeloToReturn = new Modelo();
        modeloToReturn.id = modelo.id;
        modeloToReturn.type= modelo.type;
        modeloToReturn.size = modelo.size;

        return modeloToReturn;
      })

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode simplesmente fazer um *cast* de um resultado JavaScript de uma requisição Ajax para uma instância de classe JavaScript/TypeScript. Existem várias técnicas para fazê-lo e geralmente envolvem a cópia de dados. A menos que você crie uma instância da classe (como você mesmo fez), não terá nenhum método ou propriedade. Ele permanecerá como um simples objeto JavaScript.

Minha sugestão é que você faça um *cast* para uma [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html). Uma interface é puramente uma estrutura de tempo de compilação, ou seja, possui zero impacto em tempo de execução em JavaScript. Você pode fazer algo assim:

```js
interface Modelo {
  id: number;
  type: string;
  size: number;
}
```

Utilizando a interface acima, é necessário mover a lógica do método `allowSize()` para quem tiver a referência desse array.

Por exemplo, você pode ter o código a seguir em um componente, digamos **modelo.component.ts**

```js
private modelos: Modelo[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.modelos = this.service.getAll();
}

get allowSize(index: number): boolean {
    return this.modelos[index].type != null &&
           this.modelos[index].type.toLowerCase() === 'size';
}
```

Em seguida, no seu template **modelo.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let modelo of modelos; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="allowSize(i)">Allow Size</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não entendi o porque de fazer o cast para uma interface e também não entendi essa parte: "Isso exige que você use uma classe TypeScript que use a instância de dados e execute operações com esses dados."

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor? Se puder implementar, agradeço.

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago melhorei a resposta

Comment: ah, isso eu já tinha feito. a única solução mesmo de aproveitar a orientação a objetos é fazer o que eu fiz na resposta mesmo, então? instancia o Modelo na mão e popular os dados?

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago do jeito que eu sugeri o *cast* vai funcionar para os dados que retornam. Você terá um *array* de `Modelo`corretamente populado. A única coisa que você precisa fazer na mão é a validação do método `allowSize`. O que você tinha feito é diferente, você atribuía cada propriedade individualmente.

Comment: O que eu quis dizer, é que eu já implementei dessa forma aqui no projeto, só não coloquei no post.